# android graphics and views

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I am having doubt related to working of canvas while drawing , it is mentioned that canvas holds the drawing calls and bitmap holds the actual pixel data ,for e.g in the code

```
public class MyView extends View{

    private Paint _p;
    public float x=10,y=10;
    private Canvas _canvas;
     static int cnt=0;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        _p = new Paint();
        _p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        _canvas = new Canvas();

        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cnt++;
                _canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 10, _p);
                if(cnt>3){
                    cnt = 0;
                    invalidate();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas can){
        _canvas = can;
        super.onDraw(_canvas);
        _canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        _canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, _p);
        x = x +10;
        y= y+10;
    }
}
```

3 circles should be drawn but it is not the case , can anybody please explain me?thanks in advance

Regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

Your onTouch only has a one time check to draw the circle, it's not a recursive loop to keep drawing until 3 are drawn. This is assuming your _canvase.drawCircle() event (which isn't shown) doesn't draw 3 circles.

Comment: yes that _canvase.drawCircle() inside the touch event does not draw anything on screen , correct me if i am wrong but i think 1) you cannot anything outside the onDraw() method 2) you have to use the canvas object provided by the system no other else.

Comment: I've only ever used it on the draw method, and the canvas locally as well.